# ¿Como puedo guardar una variable ConcatAdapter con SharedPreferences? Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, recyclerview, sharedpreferences

Estoy realizando un proyecto en Android Studio y Kotlin donde en el MainActivity tengo un recyclerView con multiples Adapters, empleo ConcatAdapters para mostrarlos, el problema surge cuando quiero guardar este ConcatAdapters con SharedPreferences para mostrarlos al volver a abrir la app. Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme. Gracias

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    var userList: MutableList<ExampleItem> = mutableListOf()
    var userList2: MutableList<ExampleItem> = mutableListOf()
    var adapterLst : ConcatAdapter = ConcatAdapter()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        recycler_view.layoutManager=GridLayoutManager(this,2)
        recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true)

        userList2.add(ExampleItem("cuatro", "cinco"))
        userList.add(ExampleItem("cuatro", "cuatro"))


        adapterLst = ConcatAdapter(ExampleAdapter(this, userList),typ2Adapter(this, userList2))

        recycler_view.adapter = adapterLst

        add.setOnClickListener {

            saveData()

        }


    }

    private fun saveData() {
        val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
        val gson = Gson()
        val json = gson.toJson(adapterLst)
        editor.putString("recycler list", json)
        editor.apply()
    }



}
´´´
```

Comment: Dices que el problema está cuando intentas guardar pero no cuál es. Indícalo en la pregunta por favor.

Comment: Android Studio no muestra errores y la instalación es normal en el smartphone, pero al abrir la app y picar en el botón "add" se cierra la app automaticamente.